# Ubuntu 16.04 desktop UI is broken/missing features

Tags: 16.04, unity, gui

I've been living with an issue on my 16.04 VM that I *believe* started after upgrading some system packages - not exactly sure which. It's hard to explain, but the UI in general is just a bit off, as if whatever UI package was not fully installed. A few examples:

- Context menus do not highlight items when I hover
- Console text colors are significantly different and not practical (Text is gray on a black background...)
- There is no margin or border on certain menu items, the all just run together, ie `AllSettingsAppearance`. Hovering over the items does not highlight or give any indication they are clickable. The same for routes in the Files dialog.
- Desktop background does not show (just black), though the system settings claims it is set

I can upload pics if my description is not sufficient.

I poked some in the obvious system settings, trying different themes to see if one would reset, but the issues persist. I would not be surprised if I screwed up a UI package somehow, is there something I can try reinstalling?

edit: I did try reinstalling unity, but I'm a little terrified to go too far. This is what I got:

```
sudo apt-get install unity

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
gnupg : Breaks: software-properties-common (<= 0.96.24.3) but 0.96.20.7 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

apt-cache policy unity output per @N0rbert request:

```
apt-cache policy unity gnupg software-properties-common

unity:
  Installed: 7.4.5+16.04.20180221-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 7.5.0+18.04.20180413-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     7.5.0+18.04.20180413-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
 *** 7.4.5+16.04.20180221-0ubuntu1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
gnupg:
  Installed: 1.4.20-1ubuntu3.3
  Candidate: 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2
  Version table:
     2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.2.4-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.4.20-1ubuntu3.3 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
software-properties-common:
  Installed: 0.96.20.7
  Candidate: 0.96.24.32.7
  Version table:
     0.96.24.32.7 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
     0.96.24.32.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
 *** 0.96.20.7 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy unity gnupg software-properties-common` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert added above

Comment: Your repositories are correct. Consider to run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt dist-upgrade` (to get new dependencies).